# Getting updates via POST back or query

Tags: asana

I'm working on integrating asana with another system we use.  I was hoping to find a way to get a list of recently updated tasks either by query or post back.  Has anyone had any luck doing something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can query tasks with an optional field **modified_at** .

Then choose which are recently updated by timestamp.

Example:

```
GET /tasks?opt_fields=modified_at

{"data":[{"id":1075665551337,"modified_at":"2013-02-26T04:04:34.828Z"},
         {"id":1769695992436,"modified_at":"2013-02-26T20:26:43.636Z"},
         {"id":2074657121778,"modified_at":"2013-02-27T01:33:05.860Z"},
         {"id":2095439422173,"modified_at":"2013-02-27T01:41:05.233Z"},
         {"id":2095439422178,"modified_at":"2013-02-27T01:41:05.233Z"},
         {"id":2083868998490,"modified_at":"2013-02-27T01:36:47.203Z"},
         {"id":2083868998484,"modified_at":"2013-02-27T01:36:47.203Z"}]}
```